# Magento - Hide price for users with certain zipcode

Tags: magento

I'd like to create a Magento module that would allow me to hide the price for users with certain zipcodes. (It's actually the first 2 digits of the zip code).
I am new to Magento...

Answer (score 0):

You must use GeoIP to get the zip code.

After that, you can change the code in the file 
`\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions`:

```
public function getFormatedPrice()
{
    if($geoip->getZipCode() == "your_zip_code_want_hide")
    return '';
}
```